# Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found in intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I'm getting the error

> Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found

for the below code

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I can not change the code, and it is working for my colleagues

I have tried:

> From the Preferences in Intelli J, navigate to "Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven", check the "Use plugin registry", and click "OK".
> Then "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart" to reload IntelliJ. The error will go away automatically.

But it did not work, any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was not downloaded.
Download maven for [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and extract it. Set maven location on the environment variable so that it can run from anywhere.
Open CMD/Terminal and then do:

```
mvn clean install
```

Inside the project.